# UIView automatically moving up when pushed in a SplitviewController from TabbarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

My Single View Application has a TabBar & some Tab contains Splitview. My current scenario is when I pushed a new view controller in my Tab's secondary view controller, it moves up automatically & shows a black bar top of the TabBar. Please take a look at the screenshot below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the ViewController you worked on.

Go to the Attribute Inspector.

In Attribute Inspector View Controller section

- Unmark Adjust Scroll View Insets (layout)
- Checkmark Under Opaque Bars (Extend Edges)

[image]

Hope it helps.